# Vue JS Click Function Behaves Strangely

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, dom-events, vue-reactivity

I have a vue.js component  designed like a wizard with 5 steps.
Each step of the wizard has about 4 buttons on them each button calls a function called `addPoint()` and each call passes a number to `addPoint` and `addPoint` sums it up and so on... On click of the button, I call this function and then move to the next step.

But strangely enough some buttons work when clicked and others don't.
See vue template a function.

```
<div class="row" v-if="step === 2">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>Risk Assessment</h4>
                            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                          This is <strong>{{step-1}}</strong> of 5 questions on this assesment
                        </div>
                        <p>How would you describe your knowledge of investment?</p>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(1)"  type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                None (1)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(3)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                Limited (3)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(7)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                Good (7)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(10)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                Extensive(10)
                            </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div style="padding-top:0rem;padding-bottom:0rem;width:450px;height:750px" class="col-md-6 centerimagetext" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + halfPageStartImage + ')' }">
                        <!--Image Goes Here-->

                    </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of Question 1 -->


            <!--Start of Question 2-->
            <div class="row" v-if="step === 3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>Risk Assessment</h4>
                  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                          This is <strong>{{step-1}}</strong> of 5 questions on this assesment
                        </div>
                        <p>How long do you think you can invest without withdrawing your fund?</p>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(0)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                Less than 3 months (0)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(0)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                3-12 months (0)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(4)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                2-3 years (4)
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-12 pt-3">
                            <button @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(8)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light col-md-12">
                                Over 5 years (8)
                            </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:0rem;padding-bottom:0rem;width:450px;height:750px" class="col-md-6 centerimagetext" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + halfPageStartImage + ')' }">
                        <!--Image Goes Here-->

                    </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of Question 2-->
```

Vue JS Method

```
addPoint: function(point) {
                if (this.step === 6) {
                    this.totalPoints += parseInt(this.totalPoints) + parseInt(point);
                    console.log("Total Point at the end " + this.totalPoints);
                    this.next();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("We passed " + point);
                    
                    this.totalPoints += parseInt(this.totalPoints) + parseInt(point);
                    console.log("We summed " + this.totalPoints);
                    this.next();  
                    return this.totalPoints; 
                }
               
            },
```

I notice the bug happens most especially when I'm passing 0 to the `addPoint` function. NB: No error is shown in the console.

Comment: Don't parseInt 0. Check it and pass it without parseInt.

Comment: ParseInt(0) will return NaN.

Comment: I did that i.e removed ParseInt(0) .....Still addPoint(0) did not fire.

Comment: Okay. pass 0 as 'zero' and see if it works.

Comment: `parseInt()` is intended for `String` inputs. `addPoint()` is only called with `Number`s (`point` is always a `Number`), so there's no need to `parseInt()` on `point`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse 0 to integer. `parseInt(0)` will result in `NaN`.
Check for O in addPoint method and pass it directly as:

```
this.totalPoints += parseInt(this.totalPoints) + (point != O)?parseInt(point):0;
```

Comment: The button to addPoint(0) i.e @@click.stop.capture.once="addPoint(0)"
Did not fire still even after changing my code to  this.totalPoints += parseInt(this.totalPoints) + (point != 0) ? parseInt(point) : 0;